# How to mark a dependency property to show up in Document Outline view

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml

I made a custom control with three dependency properties.
One is marked as the content dependency property using the [ContentPropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
The other two dependency properties are also of type `FrameworkElement` which are used to build up the look of the control.

My problem is, that only the content dependency property is shown in the Visual Studio Document Outline view.
How can I mark the other two dependency properties so that they show up in the Document Outline view too (e.g. with a special attribute)? Microsoft controls can do this... (e.g. the WinRT's Page class and its TopAppBar property).

Comment: I'm afraid, it's not possible to do so, see this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/064e6edb-b71c-4dfd-b594-8172447170e5/child-content-of-user-control-not-selectable-in-vs-2012-xaml-designer?forum=wpf). They suggest the Snoop utility, I would add the WPF Inspector as another candidate.

Comment: Please add your comment as answer and ill award it with the bounty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not possible with Visual Studio. The content of you additional `ContentControls` set up through DependecyProperties will not show up in the Document Outline Window, as it is described in this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/064e6edb-b71c-4dfd-b594-8172447170e5/child-content-of-user-control-not-selectable-in-vs-2012-xaml-designer?forum=wpf).

There they suggest the [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) utility to check the visual tree of a running WPF application, and I would add the [WPF Inspector](https://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/) tool as another candidate.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't mind heavier controls, instead of FrameworkElement try using a ContentControl with Properties (Height/Width) set.

Comment: This should be a comment, or expanded into a more comprehensive answer.